# Form program made up of VisualBasic6 about C# Application TopMost not working

Tags: c#

First of all, please understand that I am not good at English so I am not good at choosing or write sentence or word.

I am having an issue with C# TopMost not working.
calling method is at Called C# Application From VB6.

according to each specific situation show different from each other Form.
All forms have the following code:

```
// Define
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);

private static readonly IntPtr HWND_TOPMOST = new IntPtr(-1);
private const UInt32 SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001;
private const UInt32 SWP_NOMOVE = 0x0002;
private const UInt32 TOPMOST_FLAGS = SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE;
```

```
// All forms have the following code:
SetWindowPos(f.Handle, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, TOPMOST_FLAGS);
Commom.User32.AllowSetForegroundWindow((uint)Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id);
Commom.User32.SetForegroundWindow(h);
Commom.User32.ShowWindow(h, 1);
f.BringToFront();
f.TopLevel = true;
f.TopMost = true;
f.Focus();
// f is Form, h is Handle
```

Despite the above, it's TopMost not working.
I want you to help me if you know the problem or if you can help me.

Have a good day.

Comment: What do you mean by not working?  Does it throw an error?  Do your attempts to set topMost value meet with failure?  By more specific.

Comment: Hello!
Umm.. TopMost is Not Working. No errors, they don't work. TnT

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why do you have to make the window as much on top of everything as possible? There is likely a better way.

Comment: Isn't the `TopMost` property of the `Form` enough to make it the top most? You can't top most every single form,

Comment: I added ```SetWindowPos```, ```SetForegroundWindow``` in addition to ```TopMost``` because it doesn't work with TopMost.
It's not working just ```SetWindowPos``` or ```SetForegroundWindow```, so we put ```TopMost``` together.
Is there a problem here?

The reason why you Called ```TopMost``` that on every screen is because you see different screens in different situations, and they should all be at the top.

Comment: It will be helpful if you can manage to take a screenshot to illustrate what are you trying to achieve. Maybe we can assist you to implement a better approach.

Comment: `SetWindowPos(f.Handle, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, TOPMOST_FLAGS);` Height and Width = 0 ?

Comment: Is that a Windows Forms [`Form`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form?view=netframework-4.8)?